# Why osmdroid not working in offline mode (multiple questions)?

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am working on the `OSMdroid` library, and wanted to make it `offline` so i used this code

```
 mMapView.setUseDataConnection(false);
```

but in this condition it won't even display the map other than the graph page. But when i change the `boolean` to `true` it again starts working.

> So how do i make it work completely offline?

I am also trying to get the `poi` so i have the following code

```
 geoPoint= new GeoPoint(37.439974,-119.003906);
 double north = 84;
    double east = -180;
    double south = -84;
    double west = 180;
    boundingBoxE6 = new BoundingBoxE6(north, east, south, west);
    mMapView.setScrollableAreaLimit(boundingBoxE6);
    mMapView.setMultiTouchControls(true);
    Marker marker= new Marker(mMapView,mResourceProxy);
    marker.setPosition(geoPoint);
    mMapView.getOverlays().add(marker);
    poiMarkers = new FolderOverlay(getActivity());
    new connection().execute();
    mMapView.invalidate();


public class connection extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
        NominatimPOIProvider poiProvider = new NominatimPOIProvider();
        pois=poiProvider.getPOICloseTo(geoPoint,"atm",50,1000);
        return pois;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        mMapView.getOverlays().add(poiMarkers);
        Drawable poiIcon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker_poi_default);
        if (o != null) {
            for (POI poi : pois) {
                Marker poiMarker = new Marker(mMapView);
                poiMarker.setTitle(poi.mType);
                poiMarker.setSnippet(poi.mDescription);
                poiMarker.setPosition(poi.mLocation);
                poiMarker.setIcon(poiIcon);
                poiMarkers.add(poiMarker);
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

> But instead of getting the `poi` on the given `geopint` i get it somewhere else and everytime i mean whatever the code i change i don't get the `poi` in any other places other than that

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=[atm]&limit=50&bounded=1&viewbox=-1119.003906,1037.439974,880.996094,-962.560026
```

> Is it possible to access `poi` in offline mode?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions at once. Do you have offline [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles)? Without tiles you can't show an offline map with osmdroid. There are already multiple questions and howtos about how to use osmdroid offline, so please be very specific when asking a question about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the offline tiles showing, are you sure you have the offline map tiles `.ZIP-file` stored in `/mnt/sdcard/osmdroid/` (or whatever the path for your device's SDcard is, it just has to be within this folder in a subdirectory called `osmdroid`)?

A good tutorial that helped me can be found here: http://www.haakseth.com/?p=30

The OSMdroid TileSource will automatically look for this `.ZIP-file` if there is no internet connection to retrieve the tiles from. In the OpenStreetMapTileProviderConstants class there is this piece of code:

```
/** Base path for osmdroid files. Zip files are in this folder. */
public static final File OSMDROID_PATH = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
        "osmdroid");
```

So as you can see, you just need to have the `osmdroid`-directory in your SDcard folder, and everything should work just fine.

If you don't have a map tiles `.ZIP` yet, check out [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/) for creating this.